# recv() loop adding last "chunk" twice to buffer

Tags: html, c

Im new to C and very new to network programming. I wrote some code that would read an HTML file  chunk by chunk. Everything works great until the last chunk which gets read in twice and Im not inertly sure why.

```
char    request[] = "GET /~kkredo/file.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";      
char    response[10000];                         
int     bytes, p_count = 0;                     
int     res_code = 1;                           

send(sock, request, sizeof(request), 0);                
while(res_code != 0) {                          
    res_code = recv(sock, &response, chunk, 0);
    printf("%s",response);
    bytes += res_code;
}
```

That's the code for the loop, it prints out each chunk until the last chunk which prints twice. Ive put an If statement to double check what the loop is checking, and even though res_code = 0, it still prints. I think it has something to do with the char buffer but Im not sure.

```html
<p> that's it for this page </p>
    </body>
</html>
    </body>
</html>
```

That would be an example of the duplication. The second html and body tags are duplicated and dependent on if the chunk size is larger, then it would duplicate more of the document. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you call `printf("%s",response);` without regarding `res_code`, thus if `recv()` doesn't receive anymore data and returns 0, you print whatever still is in `response`. Furthermore: `response` isn't necessarily NUL terminated, so your printf invokes UB

Comment: `recv` does not add terminating `\0` byte to the buffer. The content of `response` is probably not a valid string

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt you should make that into an answer

Answer (score 2):

you call

```
printf("%s",response);
```

without regarding `res_code`, thus if `recv()` doesn't receive anymore data and returns 0, you print whatever still is in `response`. Furthermore: `response` isn't necessarily `NUL` terminated, so your `printf()` invokes UB. And, as a third point, your code doesn't handle that `recv()` might return `-1`.

So you should change yout loop to:

```
 while(res_code > 0) {                          
    res_code = recv(sock, response, chunk, 0); // '&' isn't necessary here
    if(res_code > 0) {
        printf("%.*s",res_code,response);
        bytes += res_code;
    }
}
```